# Scrollbar removes right part of images

Tags: css

Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
   <style type="text/css">
    div {display:inline-block; height:200px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto;}
        a {display:block;}
    img {border:0;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Except in Internet Explorer and Opera the right part of images are cut. I wonder what's the reason and how they can be displayed the same across different browsers.

To clarify the problem here's a similar code without *overflow-x:hidden*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
   <style type="text/css">
    div {display:inline-block; height:200px; overflow:auto;}
        a {display:block;}
    img {border:0;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you see an unnecessary horizontal scrollbar except in IE and Opera.

Many thanks in advance!

Mike

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Not sure what you mean by "cut"? They appear to look the same for me in Opera and in Chrome.

Comment: You have an `overflow-x: hidden` property for the parent DIV, but there is no set width on the DIV. If there were a set width, that would explain why the image might be cut off

Comment: @MusikAnimal: Setting a width seems to be a good solution, but how can I calculate it while the scrollbar width isn't always the same in different browsers/systems?

Comment: I don't understand. The scrollbar should never be in the way... it's normal browser behavior to put the scrollbar directly to the right of the overflowed container

Answer (score 0):

Hey now used to `vertical align` `top`

```
img{
vertical-align:top;
}
```

Live demo http://tinkerbin.com/GHQc5Qr7

---

Define your reset css in your css

updated demo http://tinkerbin.com/bwNH5c0I

**more info** http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you don't seem to have read my question carefully.

Comment: Hey @RainLover define reset css according your layout and now check to this http://tinkerbin.com/bwNH5c0I

Comment: I'm afraid it makes no difference.